# How to create an alias for standard 'java' execution command?

Tags: java, linux, bash, command-line, command

I want to create an alias for running the java projects on command line, like instead of putting "java classname" every time ; I want to create an alias for that 'java' command. For instance, "run classname". Is there any way to substitute standard java project execution command with our own? Thank You.

Comment: Did you looked for batch/shell script files?

Comment: Cross-posted on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/977893/how-to-create-an-alias-for-standard-java-execution-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bash file that takes the class name as parameter, place it in path call it run.
Example: `java $1`